# Помогите понять условие

Tags: c++, c

Само условие:
Создать текстовый файл, содержащий программу на языке С++. Проверить текст на равное количество закрытых и открытых скобок, **считая, что каждый оператор в программе занимает не более одной строки исходного файла.** Вывести содержимое файла и результат анализа.

У меня уже есть код который считает кол-во закрытых и открытых скобок, а потом сравнивает. Но я не понимаю что имеется ввиду во второй части второго предложения. Если у вас есть какие-то мысли, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: Это значит что вам нужно анализировать каждую строку независимо от остальных. Условие странное если вспомнить фигурные скобки у функций. Любая функция на одной строке?

Comment: Игнорируйте второй условие. Проверьте скобочную структуру для программы целиком.

Comment: хорошо, спасибо

Comment: *кол-во закрытых и открытых скобок, а потом сравнивает.* — этого в смысле языка мало, потому как `x = ) 1 + 2 (` верным оператором не назовешь...